# Unable to show updated values from Cursor when live updating SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am fairly new to Android and trying to learn how things work module by module. Here's what I am trying to do:

Show a word with a favorite checkbox (image). If a user taps on it then the database is updated and a column in database table stores its value (1 for checked, 0 for unchecked). I am using a cursor to retrieve values of both the word and favorite checkbox. Tapping on the favorite image correctly updates the database without any problem.

The problem I am facing is:

Unless I exit the application and start it again, the cursor doesn't fetch the recent changes made to the database. To explain it further, when I navigate to the next/previous word (using a button at the bottom of screen) the values retrieved aren't the latest ones i.e it seems like the cursor still has the old database values and not the updated ones.

I did search through Google, StackOverflow to get a concrete solution but it seems like I am not using the right search terms. I know this has something to do with updating cursor and the fact that requery is depreciated but again I have lost direction.

[EDIT] Using the below mentioned method to get Cursor:

```
public Cursor getWords() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = {"_id", "word", "favourite"};
        String sqlTables = "word_list";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
```

This method is called when user taps on favorite image to update the database:

```
public void setFavWord(int markFav, int wordPos) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("favourite", markFav);

    db.update("word_list", values, "_id = " + wordPos, null);
}
```

Comment: i think if you refresh the page it will work, bez if you exit the app it is working properly

Comment: After insert data to sqlite again fetch the data to update cursor and reload page.

Comment: @Sreekanth How would that help? As far as I know it is the cursor which is dealing with old data set.

Comment: @navneetsharma That seems to be a logical way out but won't that result in excessive resource usage i.e each time the favorite image is clicked, a new crusor is loaded?

Comment: Show the code that creates the cursor.

Comment: @CL. Updated the question with the code for getting the cursor as well as updating the database when favorite image is clicked.

Comment: where are you calling `getWords()`,i think you are calling this oncreate . So i said to think about refresh your activity

Comment: @Sreekanth It is being called in onActivityCreated() method of the fragment where both the word and favorite image is being shown. The code mentioned above resides in a different class.

Comment: so i think you understand what is your issue, you can solve this by calling the same function after update

Comment: @Sreekanth Yes, I think I do! But is it the right way to handle this situation? Any better way out? Whatever limited knowledge I have about Cursor, I think creating a new crusor (and dumping the old one) for each word being 'Favorited' isn't optimal.

Comment: why you want to dumping the old one, call the same `getWords()` after insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cursor is not dynamic; it shows a snapshot of the database at the time the query was executed.

When the database changes, you must execute the query again.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Sreekanth in comments section, I am updating the cursor whenever favorite image is tapped. Although it is working just fine but I think it as a workaround rather than a solution. Maybe I am wrong in saying so.